# How do I return more than one column in a 2d array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script

I'm working on this code here:

```
for (i; i < students.length; i++) {
  ss.getRange(i+1, col).setValue(students[i][0]);
  ss.getRange(i+1, col+1).setValue(students[i][3]);
  ss.getRange(i+1, col+2).setValue(students[i][4]);
}
```

Variables are declared, code works, I'm just trying to find out how I return data from columns `[0,3,4]` from row `[i]` and set the values all in one line. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to do this in JavaScript; "multidimensional arrays" in JavaScript are not *truly* multidimensional arrays, but simply arrays of arrays.  You could write a function to do this:

```
function col(arr, n) {
    return arr.reduce((a, x, i) => (a[i] = x[n], a), []);
}

// example usage:

const arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
col(arr, 0);   // returns [1, 4, 7]
col(arr, 1);   // returns [2, 5, 8];
col(arr, 2);   // returns [3, 6, 9];
```

(Note: this uses ES2015 syntax, relies on `arr` actually being an array of arrays, and uses 0-based column numbering.)

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed optimise this a bit by getting a range with multiple cells and using `setValues` (plural) with an array argument:

```
for (i; i < students.length; i++) {
    ss.getRange(i+1, col, 1, 3).setValues([
        [students[i][0], students[i][3], students[i][4]]
    ]);
}
```

If you want to take it a step further, you could do this:

```
ss.getRange(i+1, col, students.length - i, 3).setValues( 
    students.slice(i).map(function(a) {
        return [a[0], a[3], a[4]];
    })
);
```

NB: I don't know what the initial value is of *i* in your code, but if it is 0, then you don't need the `slice`:

```
ss.getRange(1, col, students.length, 3).setValues( 
    students.map(function(a) {
        return [a[0], a[3], a[4]];
    })
);
```